# AutoMapper Map value from source with method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, automapper

I have a `ProductForReturnDTO` which I wish to map from `Product` model. In the mapping process, I want to map `AverageRating` from a method called `"CalculateAverageRating"`. This method will calculate the average rating based on the total records in `ProductReview` collection.

However I got the error:

> 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'CalculateAverageRating' and no accessible extension method 'CalculateAverageRating'" when trying to include this method in the mapping.

Can anyone advise me on this?

**Product Model**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductReview> ProductReviews { get; set; }

    public Product() 
    {
        ProductReviews = new Collection<ProductReview>();
    }
}
```

**ProductForReturnDTO**

```
public class ProductForReturnDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AverageRating { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductReviewForReturnDto> ProductReviews { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductReview Model**

```
public class ProductReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Review { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

}
```

**CalculateAverageRating**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int CalculateAverageRating(this ICollection<ProductReview> productReviews)
    {
        var totalReviews = productReviews.Count;

        var totalRatings = productReviews.Sum(pr => pr.Rating);

        var maxRatings = totalReviews * 5;

        int averageRatings = (totalRatings / maxRatings) * 5;

        return averageRatings;
    }
}
```

**Mapper Profile**

```
public ProductProfiles()
    {            
        CreateMap<Product, ProductForReturnDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AverageRating, opt => {
                opt.MapFrom(d => d.ProductReviews.CalculateAverageRating());
            });
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the mapping code does not see `Extensions` class - probably you need to add some `using namespace_of_Extensions;` VS should be suggesting that if you press `Ctrl+.` on method in question.

Comment: Yes you are right, It was missing a namespace for the extension class. Thanks!